# CSS definition for view port height and width

Tags: css

I have a problem about div height with out no any content inside the div.need to automatically adjust browser height.  **Need to know about view port height and width**

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

your website will fit the viewport. A div inside would then need

```
div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

as well to fill the viewport.

```css
html, body, div {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  background: #00ff00;
}
body {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,.5);
}
div {
  background: rgba(0,0,255,.3);
}
```

```html
<html><body><div>This is inside the div. HTML has green background, body is red and the div is blue, since they overlay each other the resulting background should be greyish.</div></body></html>
```